# Google Play Service gives Warning every time for version

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, google-play

Getting warning while uploading any apk on Play Store.

> You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 4452000.
>   This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. It is
>   discouraged to use this Google Play services version unless you have
>   set the minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher

What is the actually problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version of Google Play services that you use in your app is compatible with android device that runs android 2.3(API level 9) or higher. if you want support android 2.2(API level 8), install Google Play services for Froyo from SDK manager and use that version in your project. you can set minSdkVersion to 9 if you want to use current Google Play services that you have.

Answer (score 3):

Yes actual problem is with minSdkVersion
you might have used

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

change it to

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this code.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```